# Is it worth to migrate from traditional Spring Framework environment to Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm new to Spring Boot and I need to clarify the following: is it worth to migrate from a traditional Spring Framework webapp environment to Spring Boot?

Let me explain: I have a default Spring Framework (traditional one) webapp environment, that I use to build upon new apps, with all configurations and dependencies already set. I have only to change some system specific param values (database url etc) in order to begin to work and everything works just fine.

So, considering my situation above, does it make any sense to migrate my environment to Spring Boot? Or this is just not necessary?

Comment: Not an answer, but here's a DZone article on motivations for using Spring Boot: [Why Spring Boot?](https://dzone.com/articles/why-springboot)

Answer (score 0):

i can say spring Boot and Spring MVC are not comparable or mutually exclusive.

Spring Boot provides a fast-production ready configuration to use and is a bundle for all spring configurations. This advocates for fast development with Zero XML configuration in your project
In short it builds your web application to be be a standalone JAR file with embedded servers.

That said, if you convert to spring boot today, you will learn some good things which definitely of a lot of help for your future and beneficial for project.But i will not say your your traditional framework is bad because that is not outdated, as spring supports them and all features are available with xml configurations.